# Append the files from dropzone to custom form data object

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to get the nice drag n' drop feeling for files in my application.

Now I want to get the files that you have dragged and dropped, and append it to my own formdata-object (FormData).

I'm getting the files from dropzone like this:

```
var files = $('#my-dropzone').get(0).dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
```

And I'm then trying to append to the formdata-object like this:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('tags', JSON.stringify(objectToServer));
    formData.append('files', files);
```

In the backend, I retrieve the post data like this:

```
        var tags = Request.Form.Get(keys[0]);
        var files = Request.Form.Get(keys[1]);
```

When I inspect the files variable, it look like this: `[object File],[object File]`

I have also tried to use Request.Files:

```
var file = this.Request.Files; //just empty
```

So, how can I add the relevant data for the files, to my formData-object, so my backend can treat it like files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append each file individually

```
for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++){ 
    formData.append('files', files[x]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I've tried It before, but now It's working. Thank you :)!